Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^n z^{n^2}$.
Find the radius of convergence of the power series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^n z^{n^2}$.
I am not sure if I did correct but here is what I have done.
We can rewrite the given series as
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^n z^{n^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n,$
where
$a_n =
\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}} & \text{if } \sqrt{n} \text{ is an integer}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$
Now, to find the radius of convergence, we compute
$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left| a_n \right|^{1/n}.$
The only terms of interest are those where $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer, and for these terms, $a_n^2 = n^n$. Plugging this into the formula, we compute:
$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left| a_n \right|^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( n^n \right)^{1/n^2}.$
Simplifying, we get:
$\left( n^n \right)^{1/n^2} = n^{1/n}.$
Taking the limit, we find:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1.$
Thus, the radius of convergence is:
$R = \frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$
Therefore, the radius of convergence is $R = 1$.
I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if that is correct or wrong. thanks in advance!

Out of curiosity, why not use the root test from the beginning? There is no need to introduce $a_n=\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}}$.

oh, you mean that I already had my subsequence of a_n^2=n^n ?

My  idea is  considering $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( |n^n  z^{n^2}|^{\frac{1}{n}} \right)$ which is applying the root test.

oh, treating it like a regular sum and not as a power series! and then we  get n*|z|^n<1 iff |z|<1 so R=1

I don't see why this was closed, as it is not a duplicate of the question linked.

@JoséCarlosSantos this question is not a duplicate of the one you linked, but rather of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477308, found using https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20n%5En%20z%5E%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1

@AnneBauval Right. Thank you

@MartinArgerami The link has been fixed, In case you were the voter-to-reopen, you might retract this vote.
